# Dynamic element scaling with unknown aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I have an img that I resize dynamically with CSS, but I make assumptions about the aspect ratio:

```
.interview-patient {
    width: 100vw * $interview-patient-scalar; 
    height: 281.9vw * $interview-patient-scalar;
    max-height: 100vh * $interview-patient-scalar;
    max-width: 36.75vh * $interview-patient-scalar;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
}
```

The problem is the aspect ratio varies as I load different patients.

How could I achieve the same result but without making assumptions about the aspect ratio?

Comment: When you are setting height AND width this will always apply assumptions about aspect ratio. If you set one OR the other then it should scale accordingly

Comment: You could set the width/height by aspect ratio then just set the max height or width to keep it from growing

Comment: @BryantFrankford it works fine as is, I want to avoid having any data related to aspect ratio in the code so it can work with any image.

Comment: @milo I answered a similar question a year or two ago and the solution involved two CSS rules, one for portrait type images and one for landscape.  I used JavaScript/jQuery to determine the aspect ratio of the image and then set the appropriate class.  As of CSS3, there was no way of getting this to work with a single CSS rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have to make some assumptions here because you've only included a small snippet of your CSS and no markup.

Instead of resizing your image, place it in a container and set that to fill the available space or give it a size. Then let the image roam free inside like this:

```css
.image .imageWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
.image .imageWrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <img src="http://cdn.teckler.com/images/Revanth/fd64d1530a2af6b98875117222d111d3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The aspect ratio then becomes a moot point because once the image reaches the edge of its parent it will start to scale.